# How to revert back to a previous version of qBittorrent?

Tags: software-installation, qbittorrent

qBittorrent just got updated and it's full of bugs. I have to comeback to v4.1.5. How do I do that in Kubuntu 18.10? and in apt-cache it says the version is 4.1.5 I know, but in the app itself, it shows v4.1.6. I updated my system from apt-update last time, that's how it got updated.

```
$ apt-cache policy qbittorrent
 Installed: 4.1.5.99~201905062119-6701-ea7e47d~ubuntu18.10.1  
 Candidate: 4.1.5.99~201905062119-6701-ea7e47d~ubuntu18.10.1
   Version table:
    *** 4.1.5.99~201905062119-6701-ea7e47d~ubuntu18.10.1 500  
         500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu
 cosmic/main amd64 Packages           
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status       
      4.1.3-1 500  
         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I would remove the version you have installed (`apt remove`), then download the older version (`wget`) you want and install it (`dpkg -i`) then mark that version to be held (`apt-mark` using 'hold')

Comment: @guiverc right but I will lose app data in that way

Comment: @algalw Repository version for 18.10 is 4.1.3, where does your copy come from?

Comment: The latest version for qBittorrent in Ubuntu 19.04 is v4.1.5. Have you downloaded 4.1.6 directly from qBittorrent Website?

Comment: Please add output of `which qbittorrent` and `apt-cache policy qbittorrent` to the question.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli edited the post

Comment: @N0rbert edited

Comment: @andrew.46 first time, I installed from package manager and since then updated from apt-update

Comment: Then what is the output of `which qbittorrent`?

Comment: @N0rbert /usr/bin/qbittorrent

Answer (score 1):

As for me - the best solution would be to purge the PPA and install version from the reposiotory:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
```